# How do you handle Ajax calls to the controller in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

One of the beauties of MVC is the ability to use Actions for both normal web calls as well as Ajax calls. But in doing so, I'm a little uncomfortable with my code. I'd like to know what other people think.

So I want to view the details of an item in a list. I have created a Details view. I also have decided to use hijaxing -- if a user has Javascript enabled, I want the Details form to be a popup. So for the Details.aspx, I need full html, but if it's an ajax request, I only need the form elements. So here's how I wrote my controller method:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return PartialView(GetAjaxModel());
    }
    else
        return View(GetModel());
}
```

It works, but whenever I have a giant "if" statement surrounding my entire code, it bothers me. How can I get rid of that and/or make the code better?

I could also write a separate method called AjaxDetails, but what I'd really like to write is this:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
        return View(GetModel());
}

[Ajax]
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    return View(GetAjaxModel());
}
```

But to my knowledge, there's no attribute to filter Ajax vs normal calls.

How do you write your Ajax calls?

**UPDATE**
Clicktricity does indeed have the correct answer. One additional change, however is that that since 2 controller methods cannot have the same signature, I need to write the controller code as such:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
        return View(GetModel());
}

[AjaxRequest]
[ActionName("Details")]
public ActionResult DetailsAjax(int id)
{
    return PartialView(GetAjaxModel());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct that there isn't a filter that does that - but in a typical MVC fashion, there is no reason why you couldn't write your own.

```
public class AjaxRequestAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        return (controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    }
}
```

Then you can use `[AjaxRequest]` on your action methods.

(Please note, I haven't tested this)